# about custom window title bar in win32 programming

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface

How to prevent paint client area in wm_ncpaint.

Comment: Do you mean *non* client area? The title bar is *not* part of the client area. Your question doesn't match the title, so I'm not sure what answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK during processing of `WM_NCPAINT` the client area isn't painted.

Did you mean title bar (instead of client area)? If so - it seems you should process the `WM_NCPAINT` in your custom way, doing what's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't pass WM_NCPAINT on to DefWindowProc. No non-client area will be painted for you.